# Send some additional parameters with FormData in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax, file-upload, upload

Im trying to find a way to upload some parameters along with a file using FormData but not sure where to look for it on the backend.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
<button class="btn" ng-click="uploadFile()">upload</button>
```

**Directive:**

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

**Controller:**

```
var file = $scope.aFile;
var foo = 'bar';

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
fd.append('foo', foo);

$http.post(api, fd, {

    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

}).then(function(res){

    console.log(res.data);    

});
```

**Backend:**

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);    

$result = saveFile('./img/', 'a_test_file'); /* SUCCEEDS! */

$res = array($_POST, $_FILES, $result); /* $_POST empty, $_FILES ok, $result success */

/* where is foo?? */
```

Not sure what Im missing or where to look for the additional parameter?

Comment: In the browser Network tab what does the request look like ? Do you see `foo` in the request ?

Comment: Ah! yes. I do see it under ------WebKitFormBoundaryaJaqlcgH4WzjSfri
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

bar

Comment: You may want to check the php code as to how to retrieve that value.

Comment: the problem was using `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);`. this was needed for regular post requests but screwed things up in this case.